# Is it possible to run PHPUnit with a dynamically loaded extension library?

Tags: php, phpunit, php-extension

I have a suite of PHPUnit tests for my extension, and I want to run them as part of the extension's Hudson build process.

So I want to run PHPUnit specifying the extension library to load at runtime, but I can't figure out how to do this.

My directory structure is as follows:

```
/myextension.c
/otherextensionfiles.*
/modules/myextension.so
/tests/unittests.php
```

I've tried running PHPUnit with an [configuration XML](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/appendixes.configuration.html) file as follows:

```
<phpunit>
<php>
<ini name="extension_dir" value="../modules/"/>
<ini name="extension" value="myextension.so"/>
</php>
</phpunit>
```

And then running it as follows (from the `tests` directory):

```
phpunit --configuration config.xml unittests.php
```

But then I get `Fatal error: Call to undefined function myfunction()`, so it's not loading the library.

I've also tried:

```
phpunit -d extension_dir=../modules/ -d extension=myextension.so unittests.php
```

And also `dl('myextension.so')` to the test setup, but no joy.

If it's relevant, this is using PHP 5.2 and PHPUnit 3.4.11.

I've cross-posted [this question on the PHPUnit users mailing list](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.phpunit.user/1495).

Comment: Hmm. My gut impulse would be a `dl()` in the test's `setup` method... But you're saying that doesn't work. Can you test whether the extension gets loaded at all using `extension_loaded`? Are you 100% sure you are not getting any errors related to the loading of the extension?

Comment: @Pekka - I think `dl()` would work if the extension was in the normal `extension_dir`, but unless I mess around with the file permissions I can't put it there during the Hudson build process.

Comment: ahh I see, crap, I thought `dl()` could accept any path. I was mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect not possible to set [`extension_dir`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.extension-dir) at runtime in PHPUnit since it has the attribute PHP_INI_SYSTEM [in this chart](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php).

That means it's not possible to it with [`ini_set()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php), so I assume it's also not possible to set it with the PHPUnit config `<ini name="extension_dir" value="/mydir/">`.

#### EDIT:

However, since PHPUnit is just another PHP script, it is possible to run PHP directly, and pass in the override commands this way!

This gets around the above issue, and the following works:

```
php -d extension_dir=../modules -d extension=myextension.so /usr/bin/phpunit unittests.php
```

The only problem with this approach is that PHPUnit will no longer be able to find any extensions that were installed in the normal directory ( eg `/usr/lib/php5/20060613/` ), this can be resolved by adding symbolic links from your extension_dir to the relevant files in the default extension_dir.

Comment: @therefromhere what about (shudder) copying the module into the extension_dir during runtime, `dl()`ing it and (maybe) removing it in the test's `tearDown` method? Awfully kludgy but in want of better ways....

Comment: @Pekka, yeah, that's what I was considering.

Comment: @Pekka - I found a solution, see above.